# Android Studio Toolbar as Action Bar Error

Tags: java, android

I'm learning about developing Android apps, and I am using the drawer template which uses a toolbar and integrates it into the action bar. The problem I am having occurs when I try to make one main java file which has the drawer and action bar actions. Then each actual layout would extend from the main file to perform the needed activities.

First, this is the error I'm having.

03-30 23:10:24.895 22105-22105/com.mmaengineer.runique E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mmaengineer.runique, PID: 22105
java.lang.RuntimeException:

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mmaengineer.runique/com.mmaengineer.runique.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:197)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:129)

Manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name_settings">
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends MainControls {
public static final int TL = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;  // Toast.LENGTH_LONG for longer
public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
public String gameMode;
public String double_xp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("LSprefs", 0);
    gameMode = mPrefs.getString("gameMode", "");
    double_xp = mPrefs.getString("double_xp", "");

    if (gameMode == "") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(gameMode);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText(double_xp);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

MainControls.java

```
public class MainControls extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve it would be to replace this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

with this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And leave everything else unchanged.

So, your AppTheme would be:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This way you still have all of your theme colors as you want them.  Just be sure to use a Toolbar on each Activity that you want to have an ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your activity needs to use a theme that extends from `AppCompat.NoActionBar`, not `AppCompat`.

Try changing the theme of your app (in `AndroidManifest.xml`) from

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

If that doesn't work, try adding the theme to your `MainActivity`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

[The answer from ARP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36345032/930640) basically does the same thing, but since Android Studio is kind enough to already generate the `AppTheme.NoActionBar` for you, making the same changes to `AppTheme` is just silly.

Comment: That did it. I am not sure why this only became a problem when I added a splash screen as it was a default template. But that appears to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about why you'd get this from the files Android Studio generates, perhaps you created one type of project and then changed the main Activity? Anyway, glad you got it working, consider accepting one of the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

in your **MainActivity.java** then follow these steps:

1. remove **android:theme="@style/AppTheme"** from  in your manifest.
2. Add  as below:

   > ```
   > <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   >             <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   >             <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   >             <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   >             <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
   >             <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimaryDark
   >             </item>
   >             <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   >             <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   >             <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   >         </style>
   > ```
3. Add the style in your  in your manifest.

> ```
> <activity
>     android:name=".MainActivity"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
> </activity>
> ```

Follow these steps and you can use the setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

The reason as far I understand is that you are defining the AppTheme globally, So if you don't apply a particular theme to your activity then it will take the AppTheme(that gives you the error).